# Find the volume of the region so generated.

Tags: calculus, integration

The triangular region with vertices $(0,−1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is rotated about the line $x=2$. Find the volume of the region so generated.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: well, i posted it mostly because i got no clue how to start, would be good with som pointers =)

Comment: Hint:  What shape is generated?

Comment: Use the washer method. Note you can find the volume of the "top half" and multiply by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this (shabby) schematic:[image]

The idea is to add up the volumes of all the infinitesimal cylindrical shells shown here. For any such intermediate cylinder, the radius is: $r = t$, thickness is $dt$ and height is: $h = 2(t-1)$. Thus its volume is: $dV = 2\pi rh (dt) = 2\pi t \times 2(t-1) dt$. Thus the entire volume of rotation is:
$$
V = 4\pi\int_1^2 t(t-1)dt
$$

Comment: Not sure if I understood..what do you mean by "t-1 represents the length traversed into the triangle" ? That's the part I don't seem to understand.