# Volume of rotated region

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $T$ be a right-angled triangular region with vertices $(0,−b),(1,0)$ and $(0,a)$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers.
When $T$ is rotated about the line $x=2$, it generates a solid with volume $V=\dfrac{325 \pi }{24}$.

Find $a$ and $b$.

---

I can't seem to find what i should use as height for my region. I've tried sketching it but it didn't help much. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) As $x$ varies in $[0, 1]$, the radius of the "cylinder" is $2-x$. The height of cylinder is $(a+b)(1-x)$ (why?).

2) Do not forget to also use the right angle condition to relate $a$ and $b$.  In this case the hypotenuse must be on the $y$-axis (why?).

Comment: Is the height derived from the right-angled condition? I don't understand why the radius is 2-x though. My guess would be x..

Comment: Radius is measured from the axis of revolution - the closer you are to $x=2$, the lesser is the radius.  You need to visualise this better, then the height and radius will be easy to figure out.

Comment: Isn't the schematic a bit like this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538248/find-the-volume-of-the-region-so-generated The tasks are almost identical.

Comment: Exactly. You have almost everything there. Note the radius is measured from the axis.

Comment: But how should i identify the height?

Comment: In this case, height of the cylindrical shell is the spread along y axis for the triangular cross section.