# Volume of rotated region, can't finish task..

Tags: calculus, integration

I need some help to finish this one..

Let T be a right-angled triangular region with vertices (0,−b),(1,0) and (0,a) where a and b are positive numbers.
When T is rotated about the line x=2, it generates a solid with volume V=130π/15.

Find a and b.

---

I have almost solved it, but i can't find a different way to express a and b. I guess you could use pythagoras, but I haven't found an equation that makes sense. Could anyone help?

Comment: Wasn't this asked?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541287/volume-of-rotated-region

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  draw a picture.  The right angle is at $(1,0)$.  What is the distance from there to $(0,-b)$ and to $(0,a)$?  Those are the two legs.  What is the distance from $(0,-b)$ to $(0,a)$?  That is the hypotenuse.  That gives another equation involving $a$ and $b$.